# Different colorbox calls depending on specific cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, colorbox

I am trying to do two things here. 
If someone visits the site and they have the cookie "v_regUsr" on their computer, the plan should open up normally  when they click on the link in colorbox like in my html below.

If someone visits the site and they dont have the cookie "v_regUsr" it should open up a different colorbox window when the click on it with these settings:

```
$.colorbox({width:"480px",height:"290px", iframe:true, href:"test.php"});
```

my html:

```
<a href="plan.php"  class="iframeplan"><img src="planbutton.png" border="0"/></a>
```

my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.cookie.indexOf("v_regUsr") >= 0) {
  // They've been here before.

}
else {
  //They've not been here before.
   $.colorbox({width:"480px",height:"290px", iframe:true, href:"test.php"});
}
</script>
```

is this possible?

Comment: so is the colorbox visible for users both with, and without the cookie? Or it should only be made visible for users without the cookie?

Comment: @dsaa the color box should always be visable, just different content inside he visitor with the cooke and something else without the cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be inclined to use jQuery for this:

```
if($.cookie('v_regUsr')){
    //the cookie exists
    $('a#galleryLink').attr('href', 'plan.php'); //EDIT - adds an attribute to any <a> tag with the id 'galleryLink'
    jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({/*insert your key:value paired options specific to established users here*/});
} else{
    //the cookie does not exist
    $('a#galleryLink').attr('href', 'test.php'); //EDIT - as above, but for test.php
    jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({/*insert your key:value paired options specific to new users here*/});
}
```

This simply checks for the existence of a cookie. The scripting inside the `if()` statement is taken from the colorbox website, all of the key:value pairs are [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).

The answer above assumes you use a number of `<a>` tags in your html with a common class, in this case `gallery`.

---

Edit:

See code annotations above for alterations.

This assumes you add an `id=""` attribute for each of your links, these IDs would have to be the same for each element, it's not ideal, but provided you don't need to use the ID to reference an individual entity, then it won't break.

That said, it would appear you could omit the `href=""` attribute from the link tag, and allow the colorbox API to handle this for you - you've got the right idea in your own demo code `href:"test.php"` - I haven't used this in colorbox myself so can't attest to it working.

---

Edit 2:

```
if($.cookie('v_regUsr')){
    //the cookie exists
    $('#linkOne').attr('href', 'plan1.php'); //EDIT - this assigns an attribute to an element with the ID of 'linkOne'
    $('#linkTwo').attr('href', 'plan2.php'); //as above, but for link 2
    $('#linkThree').attr('href', 'plan3.php'); //as above, but for link 3

    jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({/*insert your key:value paired options specific to established users here*/}); //this references any <a> element with a class of 'gallery'
} else{
    //the cookie does not exist
    $('#linkOne').attr('href', 'test1.php'); //EDIT - this assigns an attribute to an element with the ID of 'linkOne'
    $('#linkTwo').attr('href', 'test2.php'); //as above, but for link 2
    $('#linkThree').attr('href', 'test3.php'); //as above, but for link 3

    jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({/*insert your key:value paired options specific to new users here*/});
}
```

---

Edit 3:

```
if($.cookie('v_regUsr')){
    //the cookie exists
    $('#linkOne').attr('href', 'plan1.php'); //EDIT - this assigns an attribute to an element with the ID of 'linkOne'
    $('#linkTwo').attr('href', 'plan2.php'); //as above, but for link 2
    $('#linkThree').attr('href', 'plan3.php'); //as above, but for link 3

    jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({/*insert your key:value paired options specific to established users here*/}); //this references any <a> element with a class of 'gallery'
} else{
    //the cookie does not exist
    $('a.gallery').attr('href', 'test.php'); //EDIT - this assigns an attribute to all elements with the class of 'gallery'

    jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({/*insert your key:value paired options specific to new users here*/});
}
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wTFP4/1/) for a basic, working example of the above `href` manipulation using IDs and class'

Comment: I should have added, you'll need to ensure you're using the jQuery cookie plugin, it's [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

Comment: that works but how do i get it to call the link....all i need it now to do is to call the plan.php with out having it in the code you just gave me, so it would read in the html

Comment: does that make sense? i am one small step away, your previous code works great btw

Comment: @user3357774 edited the answer to reflect the second part of the question - hope that helps.

Comment: thank you but i cant hardcode the plan.php into the script ...on the html page there will be about 5 links to 5 different pages

Comment: you are soo close, if we can just get it to read the href in the html on the page it would work perfectly

Comment: the code you had before was fine also....i just need the link that is on the page from the image to read in side the javascript

Comment: Then assign each `<a>` element it's own ID, and insert the `href` attribute using jQuery for each of the elements. Rather than `$('a#galleryLink').attr...` use `$('#linkOne').attr...`, `$('#linkTwo').attr...`, etc

Comment: i cant have a different id, the javascript needs to be able to read the link thats attached to the id

Comment: If the original code I submitted worked, there were no id elements present in that markup. There was a class `gallery`, but no ID. In this sense, each `<a>` tag is able to have a single ID, but multiple classes - here, each of your links utilises the same class, and it's this class which colorbox is referencing. The ID, thus far hasn't been utilised - but can be for assigning a link. I'll add the mark up as an edit so you can see what I mean more clearly.

Comment: this will work, but if the cookie does not exist it should always show the same link...do i have to just duplicate it as many times as i need it?

Comment: or you could use the class to change the href. I've put together a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wTFP4/) - that pretty much captures the essence of what I'm talking about.